# Czech (?) keyboard layout identification

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I've got an ancient HP ProBook 4510s here which I'm trying to find the proper (Windows 10) keyboard for.

It's been used by a czech family, but the layout doesn't seem to match that either.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key labeled <kbd>Ç</kbd> is distinctive. Searching led me to the [Wikipedia article on Ç](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87), which has a section dedicated to computer input of this letter:

> On Albanian, French, Portuguese, Spanish, Turkish and Italian keyboards, <kbd>Ç</kbd> is directly available as a separate key

That leaves us with 6 keyboard layouts to look up in the worst case scenario.

Wikipedia (of course) has a dedicated page for every keyboard layout and I've quickly found that your laptop has the [Portuguese layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout).

Comment: Belgian keyboard has it too - 40% is French-speaking - but our keyboard is AZERTY.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Apparently Wikipedia counts them as one layout. "French keyboard layout" article redirects to [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) which says: _"It is used in France and Belgium, although each of these countries has its own national variation on the layout"_. I don't understand why they consider them one layout then.

Comment: Well, it's true they're both azerty, but when you're used to typing blind, the little differences are quite annoying.  But, trying to understand the reasoning behind keyboard layouts can harm your mental health.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I'm happy to live in a country that has completely switched over from a custom layout to the US layout, so I can just be ignorant about them ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following from the command line

```
wmic path win32_keyboard where "Description='Standard PS/2 Keyboard'" get /value
```

Note the **Layout** value, and search the value here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values?view=windows-11