# How to Detect the Appropriate Keyboard Layout/Language on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I can not find the right layout or language to my keyboard, for some characters I have to switch between French and English language to type them, the oncreen keyboard also fails to detect much what is realy printed on the physical keyboard.

Is there any way to auto-detect the proper input layout depending on the keyboard model for example?

I found this [SO](https://superuser.com/q/177305/558048), but the related program is not any better.

Note, I have a surface studio AZERTY Keyboard.
[image]

Comment: On-screen keyboard doesn't detect anything, it just uses the layout you have set for the system. Can you post a photo of your keyboard? Related question: [Czech (?) keyboard layout identification](https://superuser.com/q/1621231/194694)

Comment: Anyway, consider just setting whatever layout is standard in your country, despite it not matching what's printed on keys. All other keyboards you'll have to deal with, including your future keyboards, will use the standard layout, so training your muscle memory for a different one may be counter-productive. Or buy localizing stickers, they're cheap.

Comment: @gronostaj, Thank you, I edited to show an example, I can not find the painted-on button  in any layout!!

Comment: You've got a weird hybrid keyboard. It's AZERTY... but ANSI. AZERTY keyboards should be ISO. You'll have to ask the manufacturer if they made a layout for it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, I found Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134), and then I created a layout that match the keyboard, and added it to Windows.

[image: Keyboard Layout]